# when i try to connect to www.microsoft.com on windows web server 2008, where does it get the IPAddress?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

i have very little experience with networks, and i have a problem:

we've received a name of the mailserver we have to connect to from our deployed application (deployed on windows web server).
This address is mail.xxxxx.nl

Now the application says it's not working because it can't connect to 10.18.x.x

Now we know that address is not the correct one, so we wonder: where does this mail.xxxxx.nl address gets translated to 10.18.x.x?

Can the server has it's own translation table, or do these tranlsations always come from an external ('official') server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets its address from either the 'hosts' file, its specified DNS servers or both.

Use the command "`IPCONFIG /All`" on the server to find out the machine's DNS server/s - check they're right. Don't edit the 'hosts' file unless you really need to, it can make troubleshooting harder later on, best to actually design your solution if possible.

Comment: when you talk about "the machine's DNS server/s". Are they external machines, or can you install your own DNS server in your network and override data at that machine then?

Comment: Either/both - I think you might be a little out of your depth on this to be honest, this is quite basic stuff - have you got a local sysadmin/network guy who could help you?

Comment: nope, just a hairy guy who doesn't want to fix anything :)

Comment: But thanks anyway, i'll try google it some more